# C# compilation error with LINQ and dynamic inheritance

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, compiler-errors

Consider the following code *(for the sake of this test, it doesn't do anything of particular use - it's just to demonstrate the error that occurs)*

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> d = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
{
    { "a", 123 },
    { "b", Guid.NewGuid() },
    { "c", "Hello World" }
};
d.Where(o => o.Key.Contains("b")).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
//retuns the Guid value, as expected.
```

I want to wrap `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` using inheritance:

```
public class CustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
}
```

Here is the examle above using this derived class:

```
CustomDictionary d = new CustomDictionary()
{
    { "a", 123 },
    { "b", Guid.NewGuid() },
    { "c", "Hello World" }
};
d.Where(o => o.Key.Contains("b")).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
```

This happens...

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what is causing the issue, or how to solve it?

Comment: Apparently Roslyn does not crash with this code: http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AwgPYA2lqAxsmORCMQOKoSoBOYtOe0eEjTpiAGUgBHHNgAOwAEaVeMWpQCGIEDFIwA3thhGY8pSoBu5MABMYAWQAUASn2Hj70qGTl0AEV4MTOpcCDC2ALwwnADuOl4+/vSMEMEIztgAkBkG7ll6MABE6gUANDAAjABMAMwwAL4lbkZ5hQqlMKzANsQAcqjRnTbO9Y252YW07QUAEqjU5DAA6uRclNYF9ZkZdThZ1sSLABbcqA4L4QB8MOTEANKoCGRMyOqQIA4FbU5OxAAq5ABBLhcdRpJw4dx1bBQuSKZS0VQaLRxFAJALJVIwABcMESgRSIQAPCgeNAytYECl0LwLtgDHUgAAA=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have narrowed this down the binding to the Linq `Where` extension method.

This works:

```
   d.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(o => o.Key.Contains("b"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
```

And this works (calling the extension method statically):

```
Enumerable.Where(d.AsEnumerable(),o => o.Key.Contains("b"))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
```

but this does not:

```
   d.Where(o => o.Key.Contains("b"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
```

If I call the static extension method without `AsEnumerable()`:

```
Enumerable.Where(d,o => o.Key.Contains("b"))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
```

I get the better compiler error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from `'UserQuery.CustomDictionary'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,dynamic>>'`

So for some reason, the compiler is not able to bind the inherited class to the extension method.

The following methods also work:

- explicitly casting `d` to `IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,dynamic>>`
- using `object` instead of `dynamic`